# Перенос слова

Tags: орфография, перенос

Как правильно перенести слово ПРИБЛИЗИТЬСЯ? Мы перенесли так: "приблизи-ться", можно ли так переносить с одной строчки на другую?

Comment: Спасибо,а то в википедии написано при-бли-зи-ться

Answer (score 1):

Современные правила переноса очень либеральны и позволяют переносить любым способом с соблюдением по сути всего лишь двух правил: 1) на каждой строчке должен быть как минимум один слог (т.е. "гласная буква") и не менее двух букв всего; 2) нельзя отрывать гласную букву, а также мягкий и твердый знак от предшествующегно согласного (кроме й). Остальные правила касаются особых случаев (слов с дефисным написанием, например) и малосущественны.

Таким образом, вариант "*приблизи-ться*" допустим.
Более того, не могу даже сказать, что он однозначно хуже другого (приблизить-ся), но это отдельный разговор.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, конечно же, так нельзя. Разбейте слово на слоги. Получится "при-бли-зить-ся". Так и переносите.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант переноса допускается: можно образовать слоги -зить- и -ся, а можно -зи- и -ться.